# Can Fortran format statement be written as character string before use?

Tags: fortran

I have a Fortran program in which I use a format staement for writing  like

```
WRITE (12,'(A72,1X,A,1X,I6.6)') ALINE,SFFIX(1:NUM),LINENO
```

which works fine. However when I write a character string `fmtt' like

```
WRITE (fmtt,'(a)') trim(adjustl(sttr(2)))
```

where string 'sttr (2)`is` '(A72,1X,A,1X,I6.6) ' ` , which I confirm by printing fmtt like

```
WRITE(*,'(a)')fmtt
```

When I use string fmtt as  format in a write statement like

```
WRITE (12, fmtt) ALINE,SFFIX(1:NUM),LINENO
```

I get error message

```
forrtl : info(58) format syntax error at or near  '(A72,1X,A,1X,I6.6) '
```

Though I am not an expert I expected it to work as format is supposed to be a character string. Where am I wrong? I wanted to do this to make format dependent on user input.  Thanking you.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example and state your compiler version? From the information you've provided so far I can't see anything wrong.

Comment: Not you are not using a "format statement", you are using a "format string". I must second the request for a compilable example.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the single quotation marks '  ' are making problem. Following code is working fine.

```
implicit none
character(len=30) :: fmtt
fmtt = '(A72,1X,A,1X,I6.6)'
write(*,fmtt)"first_character","second_character",230
stop
end
```

Note that print*,fmtt give the output without single quotes. I follow the method given in http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html . Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: It is not about quotes. I need to generate a string  before I can equate to  fmtt . Something like  WRITE(STTR(2),'(a)')'"(a'//trim(adjustl(sttr(1)))//trim(adjustl(string(3)))//')"'   . Then I can equate ` fmttt = sttr(2) ` , which of course does not work.